# Runtime.getruntime.exec() not working

Tags: java, tomcat

Hi I am facing issue with **Runtime.getruntime.exec(String cmd)** actually earlier this was working fine but we installed some different version of Tomcat 6 so it is not working on server. When I am trying to debug it from locally then also it is executing but movement of file from one server to another is not happening.It is not giving error also.Is there any dependency of Runtime class with Tomcat version.
This is the code:

> String cmd1 = "cmd.exe /c move
> \\Server123\d$\excel\Products\html\" + u_user + datevalue +
> ".html" + " D:\excel\Products\html\";
>
> Runtime.getruntime.exec(cmd1);

It is not giving any error.

Comment: Please share some code and some error outputs. Your question is not clear.

Comment: First reflection but could not be the cause of your problem is use `ProcessBuilder`instead of Runtime exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get Runtime object as you write in your question via:-

`Runtime.getruntime.exec(String cmd)`
So its not getruntime its getRuntime in CamelCase.

You can use Runtime like this:-

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
    Process croppingProcess = runtime.exec(runtimeCommand)
        int processOutput = croppingProcess.waitFor()
        if(processOutput == 0){
            success = true
    //do your work here
}
```

> Or for better answer please share your code or clearly define your question where you exactly stuck.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help actually there was problem with some Tomcat account settings.The problem is solved.